# Parsing String with regular expression

Tags: android, regex

I am using this regular expression pattern "`test(.*?\\.jpg)`" in order to get the address to a JPG file out of a string . They all start with test...

Now I am facing following problem. Some of the links are ending with .JPG instead of .jpg.

How do I have to extend my regular expression to match .jpg and .JPG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work: `test(.*?\\.(?:jpg|JPG))`

Answer (score 4):

You can add `(?i)` at the beginning of the regex to make it case-insensitive:

```
"(?i)test(.*?\\.jpg)"
```